# How can I implement haptic feedback for the HTC Vive (SteamVR) similar to Valve's in The Lab?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, htc-vive

I'm building a game for the HTC Vive, in Unity using the [VRTK](https://github.com/thestonefox/VRTK) plugin as the basis for the VR interactions.

I know that VRTK provides a way to send short pulses (vibration) to the controllers, but I'm looking for a way to implement much more precise haptic feedback similar to the one used in the Bow and Arrow demo of Valve's "The Lab": The one where you could fill the bow stretching while pulling the arrow back.

I think that I had read somewhere (could not find it) that Valve had implemented this as audio signal that was played through the controllers as vibration.

Is there any public implementation of this approach, or should I implement this by myself?

Thank you

Comment: So, I'm coming back to this post after a whole year. For whoever wants the ability to do what I'm asking in the original question, VRTK today gives you the ability to do this by using the method TriggerHapticPulse found [here](https://vrtoolkit.readme.io/docs/vrtk_controllerhaptics) with  an AudioClip as the last parameter. And using it through VRTK means it will be platform independent (Oculus or SteamVR).